# Monitor incoming requests based on subdomain in api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-xray

I am using the wild card subdomain for API gateway, so the requests come from different subdomains.

eg: I get requests from abc.domain.com/api, def.domain.com/api, xyz.domain.com/api etc.

I have created dashboards and alarms in cloud watch for total request count coming to apigateway

[image]

Now I want to monitor the number of requests coming from each subdomain. I tried to filter the metric using a hostname, but it didn't work. I tried using AWS x-ray but am not able to get the exact count, it returns a sampled response.

I want to see for each subdomain whats the traffic. I can add a log for each API, but am not sure how to use it to create dashboards and alarms in cloud watch. If it's not possible in API gateway, is there any other way in which I can achieve this?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: So your cloudwatch logs contain the information about the domains that you want to count?

Comment: the log contains the host name

Comment: If there log entries have the domains, you can set metric filters in cloud watch based on the domain names. Have you considered that?

Comment: yeah but then i have to create for all the subdomains. 
i have around 60 now, and it will grew to be 400. 
Am trying to get metrics that will automatically group by subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled access logs in API Gateway for APIs as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html) then it provides a domain infomation over which you can create custom query and visualize in a graph. For a sample query take a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/analyzing-api-gateway-custom-access-logs-for-custom-domain-names/) ( you would need [grouping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_Insights_Aggregation_Functions) instead of a filter)

After setting up the custom access logs, you can query against them to find more insights using the custom domain name (**Note**: you would need [grouping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_Insights_Aggregation_Functions) instead of a filter)

> Go to CloudWatch Logs Insights console.
> In the log group text field, select the CloudWatch log group, APIGateway_CustomDomainLogs.
> Enter the following query.
>
> ```
> fields @timestamp, @message
> | filter DomainName like /(?i)(test.example.com)/
> ```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: It worked. 
We have datadog integration. I pushed these access logs to datadog and there I created a metric based on domain name and now I can see for each domain name how many requests are coming in.